# Passing URL parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing

I'd like to have a webpage where I enter certain details, and then submit and send a user a URL which takes them to another webpage where they fill in other details that are not the details I entered initially, but the values I entered are passed to their page, so I can access those values in code that I don't want them seeing or modifying. The URL I would want them to see would always be the same URL. What are my options here? The important things is that the parameters I pass cannot be modified.

[image]

Comment: are you familiar with using QueryString params in URL

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with it. I think what I was trying to get at was if there was a way to pass the params without them being seen or manipulated in the querystring. It looks like Tim's solution below is what I'd have to do, a db lookup with an ID, as I don't want to encrypt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than a few fields to pass, you should probably send the client some kind of ID (like a GUID) and use a database to look them up.

If you're dealing with a maximum of three or four fields, you could pass them as a querystring. Keep in mind as you're designing this that querystrings are visible to the end user - if they want to play with it, they can. You may be able to encrypt the data before you append it to the QS, but if you're going to go through that much trouble, you may as well just store it in a database and look it up. (It'll be a lot easier)

Comment: It appears that I would go with the database look-up, as I cannot have manipulation of the query-string happening. How would the ID or GUID get passed along, would it need to be appended to the URL querystring and then look for that ID in the database?

Comment: You'd save your values, if you're using SQL Server there's a datatype called UniqueIdentifier. Create your record, return the resulting uniqueidentifier in your code (I'd use a stored procedure with a return value), and append it to your link in the email. Then on the incoming page (the one the user clicks in the email), look up the record based on the identifier and populate the form.

Comment: Cool, I never used UniqueIdentifier datatype. Thanks for the explanations and help. I think I get it.

Comment: @kyle_13 if you set up the uniqueidentifier as your identity column, you should be able to use the scope_identity function to get the value for the record you just inserted.